# Symlink one directory, its contents and file structure to target directory, with automatic updates

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, dotfiles

Asked something similar a while ago in Unix&Linux but got yelled at, so will try again...

Let me take a directory called `DIR` with the structure

```
DIR/
|----> file1.txt
|----> file2.txt
|----> file3.txt
|----> SUB_DIR/
         |-----> file4.txt
```

What I want to do is create another directory whose contents would be symbolic links to the files and directories in `DIR`. That is, denoting symlinks by ** name **

```
LINKED_DIR/
|----> **file1.txt**
|----> **file2.txt**
|----> **file3.txt**
|----> **SUB_DIR**/
         |-----> **file4.txt**
```

From previous suggestions, I've been able to do this via `GNU Stow`:

```
stow DIR -t LINKED_DIR
```

what happens is that `file_{1,2,3}.txt` in LINKED_DIR are turned into symlinks to the corresponding file in `DIR`, and `SUB_DIR` appears as a symlink to the corresponding directory in `DIR`, but the files inside are not symlinks:

```
LINKED_DIR/
|----> **file1.txt**
|----> **file2.txt**
|----> **file3.txt**
|----> **SUB_DIR**

$ls LINKED_DIR/**SUB_DIR**
file4.txt
```

What I would further like to do is make sure that when a file is added to DIR/, the mirror directory LINKED_DIR/ updates with a symbolic link to the new file. This does not work with the setup as described, e.g. creating `DIR/file5.txt` does not lead to the symlink `DIR/**file5.txt**`, and creating `DIR/SUB_DIR/file6.txt` leads to a copy/the same file (*not a symlink*) appearing in `LINKED_DIR/**SUB_DIR**`

Has anyone found a solution to this? 
I'd like to replicate the relationship between `/usr/bin` and `bin`, where the contents in `bin` are linked to the contents in `/usr/bin`, and changes (e.g. the addition of new files) are automatically reflected.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe? What is the point? Why is a single symlink from one path to the other not good for you?

Comment: Maybe -- this started as a way to organize various dotfiles and configuration folders into a single github repo, which I gave up on. Having seen the `bin` setup, thought I would revisit this.